# convert TO_CHAR, IS_DATE to hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to convert specific data to Hive.
However, functions available in Oracle cannot be used in Hive. How can I solve this?
The applied conversion rule is as follows.

```sql
DECODE(TRUE, IS_DATE(TO_CHAR(columnname , 'YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYYMMDD',NULL)
```

In the case of `DECODE`, it was confirmed that it could be processed with `IF`.
But I couldn't find a way to change `IS_DATE` function and `TO_CHAR` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not have an `IS_DATE` function. Are you sure this is not a user-defined function? If so then you will need to look at the source code and check what it does and duplicate that in Hive.

`DECODE(a, b, c, d)` can be rewritten as a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE WHEN a = b THEN c ELSE d END
```

So your code (assuming that `columnname` is a `DATE` and you are using `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a string and then `IS_DATE` checks if it is a valid date, which seems pointless as it will only not be a valid date when `columnname` is `NULL`) would convert to:

```sql
CASE
WHEN CAST(columnname AS STRING FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') IS NOT NULL
THEN 'YYYYMMDD'
ELSE NULL
END
```

or, more simply:

```sql
CASE
WHEN columnname IS NOT NULL
THEN 'YYYYMMDD'
ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: This answer solved many of my problems. But the problem still remains. format 'YYYYMMDD' doesn't work. I'm trying a lot to solve this. It doesn't recognize data like 20221118 as a date type, so YYYYMMdd doesn't seem to apply either.
Currently my code is below and TEST2 contains data like "20221118","20221117": 
SELECT 
TEST2, 
(CASE
WHEN TEST2 IS NOT NULL
THEN date_format(TEST2, 'YYYY-MM-dd')
ELSE ''
END) AS RSLT
FROM TEST.TESTIF

Comment: omg i finally find it! code is here:  `cast(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(test2,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd') as string) AS RSLT`
thanks!